# How can I throw an unknown exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception

I have a problem similar to the one reported at:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv/windbg/thread/52000403-db16-4f33-9b38-dae79d9ba038

Adplus uable to generate full dump file for unknown exception because of the file path

We are getting a SecondChance_*_UnknownException which adplus tries (and fails) to include as part of the filename.

I'd like to try changes similar to the one suggested in the link, but I would like to test that adplus can create a dump file for me.

So, the question is, "How can I throw an unknown exception in c++?"

**Update: see MSalters comment below and mine showing how to create an unknown exception**

Also, for future reference I'm adding my adplus config file that can do full dumps and not have the problem with the asterisk in the file name.

```
<ADPlus Version='2'>
    <KeyWords>
        <KeyWord Name="MyActF">
            .dump -u /ma ${AdpDumpDir}\FULLDUMP_FirstChance_UnknownException_${AdpProcName}_.dmp
        </KeyWord>
        <KeyWord Name="MyActS">
            .dump -u /ma ${AdpDumpDir}\FULLDUMP_SecondChance_UnknownException_${AdpProcName}_.dmp
        </KeyWord>
    </KeyWords>
  <Exceptions>  
        <Exception Code="epr">
            <Actions1>Void</Actions1>
            <Actions2>Void</Actions2>
        </Exception> 
        <Exception Code="bpe">
            <Actions1>FullDump</Actions1>
            <Actions2>FullDump</Actions2>       
        </Exception>
        <Exception Code="*">
            <Actions1>Log;Stack;Void</Actions1>
            <Actions2>Log;Stack;MyActS</Actions2>
            <ReturnAction1>GN</ReturnAction1>
            <ReturnAction2>GN</ReturnAction2>
        </Exception>
   </Exceptions>
</ADPlus>
```

Some notes: this file doesn't create dumps on epr process shutdown, it does full dumps on "bpe", and has special handling for "*" dumps so adplus won't bung up creating the filename.  I might be inclined to only do the full dumps on second chance unknown exceptions...  under Actions1 for Exception Code = "*" can put MyActF or Void depending on whether you'd want a full dump or no dump.

Comment: You can't throw an exception without knowing something about its type. If you know nothing about the type of the exception you want to throw, then what goes after `throw XXX`? If you've caught an exception with `catch(...)` you can rethrow it with `rethrow`. This has nothing to do with dump files or file paths, so probably doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I don't see how the msdn link you provide is related to C++, as far as I can see it's about java exceptions. But to answer your questions: you can't throw what you don't know, with only one little exception (pun intended): You can rethrow anything you caught in a catch handler. In normal catch handlers you will at least know the basis type of the exception you caught, but in catchall-Handlers you know nothing about *what* you caught, so if you rethrow it, you in fact know nothing about what you are throwing. But I guess that's not what you were really asking for - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Does this exception crash the application at run-time?

Comment: @SChepurin - exceptions don't crash an application. Not handling them does. <g>

Comment: @Pete Becker - Thank you, this helps a lot to OP and myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Second Chance" means you're probably dealing with Structured Exception Handling (Win32), not C++ exceptions. SEH exceptions are thrown via `RaiseException()`. Its first argument is an exception code, e.g. `0xC0000005`. Obviously, not all 4 billion possible values have names. Any value which doesn't have a name is therfore "unknown".

Comment: RaiseException(45646546, EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE, 0, NULL); was good enough to get me a first chance exception which I could test in adplus.